# How to use postgres Insert ....ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE when inserting from select statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the following 3 tables. Please forgive the table names, they are part of a generic db structure naming convetions.

```
          table: tbl_331
          id (primary key, integer)
          field_3 (text)

          table: tbl_329_customid
          id (primary key, integer)
          fullname (text)

          table: tbl_331_to_tbl_329_field
          tbl_331_id (integer)
          tbl_329_id (integer)
          primary key (tbl_331_id, tbl_329_id)
```

I want to write a query which will insert values into the many to many table: tbl_331_to_tbl_320_field using matching values. If I use the DO NOTHING argument, this works.

This statement works to inserting values it finds matching.

```
    insert into schema_1.tbl_331_to_tbl_329_field_3 
    select  X.id, S.id from schema_1.tbl_329 S 
    JOIN schema_1.tbl_331_customid X on S.field_3=x.fullname
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

But I want to use the DO UPDATE so if there is a conflict, it will update the 2nd id (S.id).
For example, if I change the value in S.field_3 to some other value that matches a new ID, I want to update the ID in this many-to-many table.

```
   insert into schema_1.tbl_331_to_tbl_329_field_3 
    select  X.id, S.id from schema_1.tbl_329 S 
    JOIN schema_1.tbl_331_customid X on S.field_3=x.fullname
    ON CONFLICT ( tbl_331_id, tbl_329_id ) DO UPDATE set S.id = EXCLUDED.id
```

"This results in error message of column 'id" is ambiguous. "

If I try to use an alias like this:

```
    insert into schema_1.tbl_331_to_tbl_329_field_3 
    select  X.id, S.id as myalias from schema_1.tbl_329 S 
    JOIN schema_1.tbl_331_customid X on S.field_3=x.fullname
    ON CONFLICT ( tbl_331_id, tbl_329_id ) DO UPDATE set S.id = myalias
```

I get "column myalias does not exist"

I am very new to this syntax of DO UPDATE. my assumption was that after ON CONFLICT, you have to specify the uniqye/primary key that it would conflict on and then tell it what to update.

How would I write this so that It would update the matching the new matching ID?

Comment: The `on conflict` clause is meant to update rows in the target table (here, `tbl_331_to_tbl_329_field_3`), not rows from the source table... Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes, in that table is 2 keys. tbl_331_id and tbl_329_id . In this case, I want to udpate the tbl_329_id if there is a conflict.

Comment: This does not make sense to me. This column is part of the `on conflict` target, so you know already that the value is the same: updating it won't actually change the value.

Comment: I think the issue is that I am wanting a a single combination of keys, not many to many...which it's allowing. need to reconfigure the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into schema_1.tbl_331_to_tbl_329_field_3 
select  X.id, S.id from schema_1.tbl_329 S 
JOIN schema_1.tbl_331_customid X on S.field_3=x.fullname
ON CONFLICT ( tbl_331_id, tbl_329_id ) DO UPDATE set S.id = EXCLUDED.id
```

1. The context of this type of `UPDATE` is only that special table named `EXCLUDED` itself. Your input tables are not visible from within that `UPDATE`, and you only see your conflicting records (`EXCLUDED`) and the fields you're trying to insert them into (columns of `schema_1.tbl_331_to_tbl_329_field_3`). Therefore your `S` isn't reachable and there is no need for it to be - in `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` you're solving a conflict exclusively between your incoming data and what's already in the target table - Postgres doesn't mind where you got it and doesn't even try to remember.
2. `ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous` is pretty unintuitive. Even though you are free to alias the columns in your input whatever you like - as long as their order and type match your target - on conflict they are approached as if they were already in the target table. Therefore your first `id` and second `id` (or later `myalias`) are actually already called `tbl_331_id` and `tbl_329_id` respectively in the `EXCLUDED` table. The reason you get the error is because Postgres checks for ambiguity **first** and immediately throws the error at that point, before it checks whether those columns belong in your current context.
3. `S.id = myalias` doesn't make much sense because it's exactly `S.id` that you just aliased as `myalias`.

Comment: thx, I realized that my table design was wrong for what I was looking to do.